# Calculating combination in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a javascript to calculate combination and works great. But when I tried to work on Android studio code it gets wrong result.

Js

```
var n=16;
 var r=2;


function faktor(sayi) {
        
        var sonuc=1;
        for(var i=1;i<=sayi;i++)
            {
                sonuc*=i;
            }
            return sonuc;
    }
 
    function calculate (){
        
        var sonuc2=faktor(n)/(faktor(r)*faktor(n-r));
        console.log(sonuc2);
     }

calculate();
```

Console log = 120

That's how I used in Android Studio

```
    public static int tiklanan = 16;
    public static int kombinasyon = 2;
    int sonuc2;


    private int faktor(int sayi){

        int sonuc=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=sayi;i++)
            {
                sonuc*=i;
            }
            return sonuc;
    }
    
    private void posibilityhesapla(){
        
        sonuc2=faktor(tiklanan)/(faktor(kombinasyon)*faktor(tiklanan-kombinasyon));
        Toast.makeText(this, "/"+sonuc2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 
        
    }
```

sonuc2 always returns -1 but it must 120.

What I'm missing here ?

Comment: Do you ever call the `posibilityhesapla` method ?

Comment: Yes,i did.But like I said it returns -1

Comment: stackowerflow))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dorbagna your Integer variable has overflowed the value. Converting sonuc from int to long will fix your issue.

faktor(tiklanan) = faktor(16) = 20922789888000

While maximum value int can hold is 2147483647 (Integer.MAX_VALUE)

```
    public static int tiklanan = 16;
    public static int kombinasyon = 2;
    // Change variable int type to long
    long sonuc2;
    
    //change return type to long
    private long faktor(int sayi) {
        // Change local variable int type to long
        long sonuc = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= sayi; i++) {
            sonuc *= i;
        }
        return sonuc;
    }

    private void posibilityhesapla() {
        sonuc2 = faktor(tiklanan) / (faktor(kombinasyon) * faktor(tiklanan - kombinasyon));
        Toast.makeText(this, "/" + sonuc2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```